# Configure Opera to open linked tabs next to current but blank tabs at end

Tags: opera, browser-tabs

Is there any way to make new, blank tabs open at the end of the address bar, but tabs opened from a link next to the active tab? Like Firefox can do?

Comment: about:config has none, doubt, but the setting may be in opera config files somewhere, as with adding GMail as mail service case.

Comment: Look in the preferences area. Opera is pretty flexible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Settings / Preferences (or CTRL-F12), and then Advanced / Tabs, and check "Open new tab next to active." However, that also opens new tab next to active... except if you open new tabs by doubleclicking at the end of tab bar.

Comment: Ah, the wonderful world of today, where stuff is continuously fucked up.   THIS DOES NOT WORK ANYMORE.  No such option anymore in current Opera (and I think it has been removed years ago).

Comment: Alas, I wrote this answer before Opera switched to Chromium, which is probably when this solution stopped working.

Answer (score 1):

Opera doesn't have this feature anymore (all the answers, including the accepted one, are outdated).

The only recourse seems to be the "Classic Tabs" extension.

Answer (score 0):

`opera:config#UserPrefs|OpenPageNextToCurrent` is as close as you get, but as you say, new tabs are then also opened next to current.

I find this setting appalling myself, and Opera's standard behaviour is one of the reasons I stick with it (even though it has been subject to some long outstanding bugs: DSK-309187 and DSK-276359, making minimization behaviour act erroneously).

Comment: The fact that I cannot configure such a simple feature is a reason I won't be sticking with it, it just doesnt suit my workflow.

Comment: It's a question of habit. I much prefer Opera's standard way of handling it, in that it behaves more deterministic in my eyes, thus enabling faster and more intuitive navigation (for me). The simple algorithm that says that newer tabs are further to the right, period, has been hardwired into my brain :-)